# Firestore Full-Text Search with Algolia - Filters Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am currently working on implementing Firestore full-text search with the Algolia extension, and I've encountered an issue with the filtering mechanism. Here's a detailed description of the problem:

**Issue:**
I have set up Firestore full-text search with the Algolia extension and configured it to index a Firestore collection named `stories`. This collection contains documents with a complex structure, including nested fields. I want to filter search results based on specific criteria such as `gender`, `city`, and `country` within the Firestore documents, but I'm facing difficulties in achieving the desired results.

**Problem Details:**
When I send a request without any parameters, my search function returns all results, which is expected behavior. However, when I send a request with parameters like `gender=female`, `city=Bethlehem`, or `country=Pakistan`, the search function does not return any matching results, even though I know there are documents that should match these filters. I have modified my filtering code to use `uploader.gender`, `uploader.city`, and `uploader.country` to reflect the nested structure within my Firestore documents, but the issue persists. Interestingly, if I use the search parameter, like `search=female`, I get results that match the search term.

I've included the code and detailed information about my Firestore document structure in below for reference. Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this issue and how to correctly set up filtering with Algolia for such complex Firestore documents? I would greatly appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or solutions to help me resolve this issue and make my Firestore full-text search function work as expected. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

This is the cloud function which I have written to filter out stories:

```
export const filterStories = functions
  .runWith({ maxInstances: 5 })
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
      if (request.method !== "GET") {
        response.status(400).send("Invalid request method");
        return;
      }

      const {
        gender,
        city,
        country,
        orderBy = "username",
        sortDirection = "asc",
        page = 0,
        search = "",
        hitsPerPage = 10,
      } = request.query;

      let filters = [];
      if (!!gender) filters.push(`gender:${gender}`);
      if (!!city) filters.push(`city:${city}`);
      if (!!country) filters.push(`country:${country}`);

      const searchOptions = {
        filters: filters.join(" AND "),
        hitsPerPage: hitsPerPage,
        page: page,
        offset: 10 * page,
      };

      const index = client.initIndex("stories");
      const query = index.search(search, searchOptions);
      const data = await query;

      response.status(200).json({
        status: "ok",
        data: {
          length: data.nbHits,
          hits: data.hits,
          pages: data.nbPages,
          page: data.page,
        },
      });
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.codePrefix === "auth") {
        response.status(401).json({
          status: "fail",
          data: "Please login to access this resource",
        });
        return;
      }
      response.status(500).json({
        status: "fail",
        data: error.message,
      });
    }
  });
```

This is the typescript interface of what a single story object in firestore looks like, basically i am only filtering on `uploader` field in story object:

```
interface StoryInt {

  id: string;

  uploader: User;

  lastActivity: any;

  stories: {

    id: string;

    type: string;

    hasTrack?: boolean;

    track?: string | null | undefined;

    media: string;

    createdAt: any;

    isBoosted?: boolean;

    boosts?: {

      type: string;

      purchasedAt: any;

      boostExpiresAtViews: any;

      isExpired: boolean;

    }[];

    source: string;

    likes?: {

      userId: string;

    }[];

    viewers?: {

      userId: string;

      username: string;

      profilePic: string;

      seenAt: any;

    }[];

  }[];

}
```

```
interface User {

  gender: Gender;

  username: string;

  email: string;

  birthday: string;

  isAnonymous?: boolean;

  ban: boolean;

  birthdayMills?: number;

  fcmToken?: string;

  profilePictures: SingleProfilePicture[];

  bio: string;

  uid: string;

  isPro?: boolean;

  joinedOn: string;

  city?: string;

  country?: string;

  tags?: any;

  promotes?: {

    type: string;

    purchasedAt: any;

    expiresAt: any;

    isExpired: boolean;

  }[];

  showFrame?: boolean;

  activeFrame?: string;

  frames?: {

    name?: string;

    buyer?: string;

    source?: string;

  };

  following?: {

    followedAt: any;

    followedUserId: string;

  };

  followers?: {

    followedAt: any;

    followerUserId: string;

  };

}

type Gender = "male" | "female" | "other";

type SingleProfilePicture = { url: string; source: string };
```